# jQuery .trigger('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting this to work. I would like to trigger the second link. If anyone can help that would be much appreciated.

```
    $(".links").click(function () {
        alert($(this));
    })


    function someFunction(){
        $(".links").trigger('click');
    }

    someFunction();

    ...
    <a href="1.html" class="links">One</a>
    <a href="2.html" class="links">Two</a>
    <a href="3.html" class="links">Three</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have `someFunction()` accept an argument that is the 0 based index of link you want to click.

```
function someFunction( n ){
    $(".links:eq(" + n + ")").trigger('click');
}

someFunction( 1 ); // Pass 1 to trigger the second link
```

This uses [the `:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). You could also use [the `.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) if you wanted.

```
function someFunction( n ){
    $(".links").eq( n ).trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To trigger for the second link only:

```
$(".links").eq(1).trigger('click');
```

.eq(n) reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index. The index is zero based.

Comment: how to do this for all?

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions did not work for me.

But this solution works for me.

```
$('#elementID').click(function () {
    //some stuff
});
```

I need trigger to work when the page is loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#elementID').trigger('click');
});
```

OR

If you do not need to run when the page is loaded, you can use it in the function.

```
function someFunction(){
    $('#elementID').trigger('click');
}
```